# Ceiling fan light flickers one time when fan is turned off with switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan, led

We recently updated our knob and tube wiring to grounded wiring. We have a ceiling fan with a light (I believe it is Merwry 52 in Integrated LED Indoor from Home Depot, but not positive - it came with the house).

Problem: When we use the switch to turn off the fan (with the light off), the light flicks once as the power switches off.

-This does not happen when the fan is turned off with the remote.

-Both the fan and light are on the same switch.

-It is not a dimmer switch.

Is this a wiring issue?
Is this an issue with the LED light?
Why does this occur with the switch and not the remote?

Comment: can you still use the remote if the wall switch(s) are off? If not, I think I can explain it.

Comment: No, the remote doesn't work if the wall switch is off. What do you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there's anything wrong with it per se, that's just how it's made/designed. The cause is quite complex, but I'll try to explain.

Keep in mind that the built-in LED is very sensitive to even small amounts of power.

When you use the remote to turn it off, a tiny computer in the fan either tells the LED's DC power supply to turn off, or it disconnects the LEDs from the DC power using a transistor, and the light shuts cleanly off.

When you use the switch, that tiny computer is unplugged and cannot control anything, so the effect is indeterminate. There's enough residual power in the power supply that finds it's way to the LEDs without a controller controlling. It could even be generated (literally) by the fan still spinning, inducing a current that flows back into the incoming supply and drains the only place it can; the light.

At any rate, it's harmless, if annoying. You could hack apart the fan and make some adjustments to the circuitry, but that will void the warranty, bother your insurance, and risk breaking things, all for a rather small payout.

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense. Any thoughts why this wasn't happening (that we noticed) with the knob/tube, but has been with updated wiring?

Comment: Didn't realize there was a before and after in play here. That doesn't make a lot of sense and the only explanation i can posit is a little concerning: your KT was in poor shape and had a lot of resistance.  That could be from corrosion, rats, etc, but it's dangerous and wasteful. Anyway, the lossy circuit path delivered fewer volts to the fan when running, leaving less stray power in the capacitors (I think we can rule-out still-spinning motor generation) to migrate into the LEDs. Just a few extra volts is enough to excite LEDs, and new wiring may have added just that. Just a guess though...